# Grouping multiple records with the same X value in D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create grouped bar chart for performance test results. This is my first time using D3.

The X axis should show `parallelism`, which is how many threads were used and the Y chart duration in milliseconds. If multiple records are present for the same X value (same parallelism), they should appear next to each other, ideally sorted by duration but it does not matter.

I took my inspiration in this code: https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart/2?intent=fork

I spent over an hour fiddling with it, but I am still not getting the grouping right. The problem is certainly caused by how I define `fx` and `x` functions and how I assign `.attr("x", d => marginLeft+fx(d.duration))`. I tried many many variants, to no avail.

```js
const runData = [
      {"duration":74950.52171194553,"parallelism":1},
      {"duration":88687.86499893665,"parallelism":0,"exitCode":0},
      {"duration":60000,"parallelism":1,"exitCode":0},
      {"duration":90000,"parallelism":0,"exitCode":0},
      {"duration":90000,"parallelism":0,"exitCode":0}
  ];

  const width = 700;
  const height = 400;
  const marginTop = 10;
  const marginRight = 10;
  const marginBottom = 20;
  const marginLeft = 40;
  // Create the SVG container.
  const svg = d3.select("#ca")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  const paralelismSet = new Set(runData.map(x=>x.parallelism));
  const paralelismList = runData.map(x=>x.parallelism);
  paralelismList.sort();
  const durationSet = new Set(runData.map(x=>x.duration));

  const minDuration = Math.min(...durationSet);
  const maxDuration = Math.max(...durationSet);

  // I am trying here to sort by duration but group by parallelism
  const fx = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(durationSet)
      .rangeRound([marginLeft, width - marginRight])
      .paddingInner(0.1);

  const x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(paralelismList)
      .rangeRound([0, fx.bandwidth()])
      .padding(0.05);

  const color = d3.scaleLinear([minDuration, maxDuration], ["green", "red"]);

  // Y encodes the height of the bar.
  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, maxDuration]).nice()
      .rangeRound([height - marginBottom, marginTop]);

  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll()
    .data(d3.group(runData, d => d.parallelism))
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", ([paralelism]) => `translate(${x(paralelism)},0)`)
    .selectAll()
    .data(([, d]) => d)
    .join("rect")
      // I tried various combinations of subtracting fx from x and vice versa
      .attr("x", d => marginLeft+fx(d.duration))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.duration))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", d => y(0) - y(d.duration))
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.duration));

  // The horizontal axis does not work well either, it is too short
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},${height - marginBottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // This code works fine
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${marginLeft},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
      .call(g => g.selectAll(".domain").remove());
```

```html
<div id="ca">
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot you are following as an example, to me, is unnecessarily confusing.  It doesn't follow the usual `d3` graph construct, there's way too much fiddling with margins and the data manipulation could use clean up.

That said, I heavily refactored your attempt.  I added comments to explain changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="ca"></div>
    <script>
      const runData = [
        { duration: 74950.52171194553, parallelism: 1 },
        { duration: 88687.86499893665, parallelism: 0, exitCode: 0 },
        { duration: 60000, parallelism: 1, exitCode: 0 },
        { duration: 90000, parallelism: 0, exitCode: 0 },
        { duration: 90000, parallelism: 0, exitCode: 0 },
      ];

      // this is usual d3 plot set
      var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
          width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // create the container with margins for axix
      // plotting happens in the offset child g
      var svg = d3.select("#ca")
        .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      const groupedData = d3.group(runData, d => d.parallelism); //<-- group the data upfront
      const durationDomain = d3.extent(runData, d => d.duration); //<-- min and max of duration
      const innerDomain = d3.range(0, d3.max(groupedData, d => d[1].length)); //<-- domain inside the group
      const outerDomain = Array.from(groupedData.keys()).sort(); //<-- domain of the groups

      // scale of groups
      const fx = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(outerDomain)
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .paddingInner(0.1);

      // scale inside group
      const x = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(innerDomain)
        .rangeRound([0, fx.bandwidth()])
        .padding(0.05);

      // color of each bar ordered by index
      const color = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(innerDomain)
        .range(['orange', 'steelblue', 'brown']);

      // duration y-scale
      const y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, durationDomain[1]])
        .nice()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

      svg
        .append('g')
        .selectAll()
        .data(groupedData)
        .join('g')
        .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${fx(d[0])},0)`) //<-- move group to position
        .selectAll()
        .data(([, d]) => d)
        .join('rect')
        .attr('x', (d,i) => x(i)) //<-- set position inside group
        .attr('y', (d) => y(d.duration))
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', (d) => y(0) - y(d.duration))
        .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i));

      svg
        .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(fx));

      svg
        .append('g')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have, in the mean time found some hacky workaround by indexing the entries, but this looks much better. And all the margin fiddling is causing my solution to still be misaligned, so thanks a lot for clearing that up.

Comment: I just noticed a bit of a problem: This sorts the groups alphabetically, so it does not work with parallelism with two decimal numbers

Comment: @TomášZato, not sure I follow -- https://plnkr.co/edit/HAZvuqlGqQkKYHlX?preview

Comment: This is the case where the problem occurs: https://plnkr.co/edit/igq0fzq8993vwhEK But I already figured it out. `.sort` coerces array values to string, even numbers. So sorting lambda must be passed into it. `(a,b)=>a-b`. One last question: Is there no way to ask d3 for the size of the axis? Ideally, I'd expect the margins to be 0 and offset the graph based on how big the axes are. Ie. `margin.left = horizontalAxis.getWidth()`. Something like that. Manually trying the right margin seems weird.

Comment: @TomášZato, with way I've set up the graph, the pixel width of the x-axis is the range of the fx scale, which is just `[0, width]`, so the pixel width is just the `width` constant.  If for some reason it's been messed with you can get it from the svg directly -- `xAxis.node().getBBox().width`, example -- https://plnkr.co/edit/HAZvuqlGqQkKYHlX